# Electron indistintinguishability and handedness

Tags: fermions, chirality

I just learned that right ad left handed  electrons behave in a remarkably different way under the weak interaction.

Up till now I have been told that all the electrons are exact copies of one another and all this fermi-dirac statistics story.

Nonetheless, since right handed and left handed electrons DO have fundamental differences, shouldn't this remove their indistinguishability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A massive electron in its rest frame is a mixture of left- and right-handed components. All electrons mix the same way, and so they remain indistinguishable.